# How to declare check boxes values to String values on flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my code can select multiple checkboxes, but I want to print the selected checkboxes titles.And also then application run checkboxes are unselecting ( checkboxes values are bool = false)

[image]

Ex: Like as this Image I selected dart and java checkboxes so I want to display those names in the console.I have no idea how to equal the check box value to string values.
How to print that values?

code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePageWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageWidgetState createState() => _HomePageWidgetState();
}

class _HomePageWidgetState extends State<HomePageWidget> {
  bool? checkboxListTileValue1;
  bool? checkboxListTileValue2;
  bool? checkboxListTileValue3;
  bool? checkboxListTileValue4;
  bool? checkboxListTileValue5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          'Page Title',
        ),
        actions: [],
        centerTitle: false,
        elevation: 2,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                  unselectedWidgetColor: Color(0xFF95A1AC),
                ),
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                  value: checkboxListTileValue1 ??= false,
                  onChanged: (newValue) async {
                    setState(() => checkboxListTileValue1 = newValue!);
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    'c++',
                  ),
                  tileColor: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                  dense: false,
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                ),
              ),
              Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                  unselectedWidgetColor: Color(0xFF95A1AC),
                ),
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                  value: checkboxListTileValue2 ??= false,
                  onChanged: (newValue) async {
                    setState(() => checkboxListTileValue2 = newValue!);
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    'c',
                  ),
                  tileColor: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                  dense: false,
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                ),
              ),
              Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                  unselectedWidgetColor: Color(0xFF95A1AC),
                ),
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                  value: checkboxListTileValue3 ??= false,
                  onChanged: (newValue) async {
                    setState(() => checkboxListTileValue3 = newValue!);
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    'java',
                  ),
                  tileColor: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                  dense: false,
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                ),
              ),
              Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                  unselectedWidgetColor: Color(0xFF95A1AC),
                ),
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                  value: checkboxListTileValue4 ??= false,
                  onChanged: (newValue) async {
                    setState(() => checkboxListTileValue4 = newValue!);
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    'react',
                  ),
                  tileColor: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                  dense: false,
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                ),
              ),
              Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                  unselectedWidgetColor: Color(0xFF95A1AC),
                ),
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                  value: checkboxListTileValue5 ??= false,
                  onChanged: (newValue) async {
                    setState(() => checkboxListTileValue5 = newValue!);
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    'dart',
                  ),
                  tileColor: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                  dense: false,
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePageWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageWidgetState createState() => _HomePageWidgetState();
}

class _HomePageWidgetState extends State<HomePageWidget> {
  bool? checkboxListTileValue1;
  bool? checkboxListTileValue2;
  bool? checkboxListTileValue3;
  bool? checkboxListTileValue4;
  bool? checkboxListTileValue5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          'Page Title',
        ),
        actions: [],
        centerTitle: false,
        elevation: 2,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                  unselectedWidgetColor: Color(0xFF95A1AC),
                ),
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                  value: checkboxListTileValue1 ??= false,
                  onChanged: (newValue) async {
                    print('c++');
                    setState(() => checkboxListTileValue1 = newValue!);
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    'c++',
                  ),
                  tileColor: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                  dense: false,
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                ),
              ),
              Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                  unselectedWidgetColor: Color(0xFF95A1AC),
                ),
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                  value: checkboxListTileValue2 ??= false,
                  onChanged: (newValue) async {
                    print('c');
                    setState(() => checkboxListTileValue2 = newValue!);
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    'c',
                  ),
                  tileColor: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                  dense: false,
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                ),
              ),
              Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                  unselectedWidgetColor: Color(0xFF95A1AC),
                ),
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                  value: checkboxListTileValue3 ??= false,
                  onChanged: (newValue) async {
                    print('java');
                    setState(() => checkboxListTileValue3 = newValue!);
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    'java',
                  ),
                  tileColor: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                  dense: false,
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                ),
              ),
              Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                  unselectedWidgetColor: Color(0xFF95A1AC),
                ),
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                  value: checkboxListTileValue4 ??= false,
                  onChanged: (newValue) async {
                    print('react');
                    setState(() => checkboxListTileValue4 = newValue!);
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    'react',
                  ),
                  tileColor: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                  dense: false,
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                ),
              ),
              Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                  unselectedWidgetColor: Color(0xFF95A1AC),
                ),
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                  value: checkboxListTileValue5 ??= false,
                  onChanged: (newValue) async {
                    print('dart');
                    setState(() => checkboxListTileValue5 = newValue!);
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    'dart',
                  ),
                  tileColor: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                  dense: false,
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```